# I am having a slash of headers before the animation brings them in from the side. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a website to put all my projects and resume on and I am using some animation to bring in the title elements in from the side on load as you can see in the snippet below.  But when the page initially loads the title text flashes really quickly then the JavaScript loads and brings them in from the sides.  Is this a preloading issue? It hasn't seemed to fix it.

Is it a matter of which order the elements/JavaScript is loaded? Or am I missing some line in my JavaScript that prevents this?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    /* Function to bring in navbar from top staggered */
    gsap.from(".btn",{duration:2,opacity:0,y:-300,stagger:0.25,});

    /* Function to bring h1 in from the left */
    gsap.from("h1",{duration:2.5,ease:"power2.out",x:-2000});

    /* Function to bring in h2 from right */
    gsap.from("h2",{duration:2.5,ease:"power2.out",x:2000});

    /* Function to register gsap scroll plugin */
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollToPlugin);

    /* Function to scroll to About me when button is clicked */
    document.getElementById('scroll').addEventListener('click', function clicked() {
    gsap.to(window, {duration: 0.8, scrollTo:'#red' });
    });

});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #24305E;
    height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
    color: #A8D0E6;
    font-display: fallback;
    font-size: 15vh;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 12vw;
    text-shadow: 
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    -8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18),
    -10px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),
    -12px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    -14px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),
    -16px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),
    -18px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
    -20px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
    -22px 22px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    -24px 24px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09),
    -26px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08),
    -28px 28px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
    -30px 30px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),
    -32px 32px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
    -34px 34px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
    -36px 36px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03),
    -38px 38px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}


h2 {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif;
    font-display: fallback;
    color: #F8e9a1;
    font-size: 15vh;
    margin-left: 12vw;
    text-shadow:
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    -8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18),
    -10px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),
    -12px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
    -14px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),
    -16px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.13),
    -18px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
    -20px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.11),
    -22px 22px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
    -24px 24px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09),
    -26px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08),
    -28px 28px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
    -30px 30px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),
    -32px 32px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
    -34px 34px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
    -36px 36px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03),
    -38px 38px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }

h3 {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    color: #f99f9f;
    font-size: 3vh;
    margin-left: 13vw;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    text-shadow:
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
h4 {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    color: #f99f9f;
    font-size: 3vh;
    margin-left: 13vw;
    margin-top: 5vh;
    text-shadow:
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h5 {
    font-size: 5vh;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans SC', sans-serif;
    color: #f8e9a1;
    padding: 20px; 
    margin: 5vw;
    text-shadow: 
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

h5:after {
    background-color: #F8E9A1;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;   
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 
  -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
  -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
  -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
  -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}

#red {
    color: #f99f9f;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box {
    margin-top: 20vh;
    width: 66vw;
    height: 15vh;
    margin-left: 12vw;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 75px;
}

p {
    color : #A8D0E6;
    font-size: 2.75vh;
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    margin-left: 8vw;
    text-shadow:
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

hr {
    height: 1vh;
    background-color: #A8D0E6;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 6vw;
    margin-right: 6vw;
}


img {
    float: left;
    width: 25vw;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 30px;    
    box-shadow: 
  -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
  -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
  -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
  -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}


.imageContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
.imageContainer:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 7px solid #F8E9A1;
    content: '';
    z-index: -2;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 
  -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
  -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
  -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
  -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}

.btn {
    font-family: 'Courier Prime', monospace;
    color: #F8E9A1;
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #F8E9A1;
    color: #24305E;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    box-shadow:
    -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1),
    -2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
    -4px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    -6px 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
    -8px 8px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.18),
    -10px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),
    -12px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),
    -14px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12),
    -16px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.10),
    -18px 18px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.09),
    -20px 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08),
    -22px 22px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.07),
    -24px 24px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06),
    -26px 26px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
    -28px 28px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
    -30px 30px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03),
    -32px 32px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.02),
    -34px 34px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
 }

.zoom {
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courier+Prime&family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@700&display=swap" as="font">
      <script src="main.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <title>Matthew Salem | Software Engineer</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style="background-color: #24305e;">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.matthewsalem.com"> Matt Salem Logo </a>
         <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="zoom">
               <div class="btn-group mr-5" role="group" aria-label="First group"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" id="scroll" type="button">01. About Me</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zoom">
               <div class="btn-group mr-5" role="group" aria-label="Second Group"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="button">02. Portfolio</button></div>
            </div>
            <div class="zoom">
               <div class="btn-group mr-5" role="group" aria-label="Third Group"> <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" type="button">03. Resume</button></div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <h3>Hello! My name is</h3>
   <div id="animate">
      <h1>Matthew Salem.</h1>
   </div>
   <h4>I am a</h4>
   <h2>Software Engineer</h2>
   <h4>experienced in front end website architecture and back end application development.</h4>
   
   <div class="box">
   <h5><div id="red">01.</div>  About Me</h5>  
   </div>

     <div class="content">
      <div class= "column">
      <p>Hi! My name is Matt Salem.  I am a software engineer based out of 
         New Haven, CT.  Currently I am a student at the Holberton School.
         I love buliding awesome software, especially any projects in the field 
         of web development.  My goal is to build products that give the user
         not only functional service or tool, but an experience that they will
         remember.  When I am not working on a project, you can find me 
         with friends out to eat, playing chess and drinking coffee downtown, 
         or enjoying a live show at Toad's Place or any other local venues.
      </p>
      </div>
   <div class="column">
      <div class="imageContainer">
      <img src="IMG_3152 (1).jpg" alt="Headshot">
         </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

It means your webpage will render before the callback is executed.

I would suggest to use `gsap.to` (https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.to()) instead. You could add your initial position in your CSS, which can then be reset by with `gsap.to`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `<script src="main.js"></script>` to the very bottom of the html body so that everything else runs first. I just finished adding some animations to a project...here is how I did it:

```
window.onload(animations());

function animations(){
    const tl = gsap.timeline({defaults: {ease: "power1.out"}});

    tl.to(".intro", {y: "-100%", duration: 1, delay: 1});
    tl.fromTo(".intro", {opacity: 1}, {opacity: 0, duration: 1}, "-=1");
    tl.fromTo(".card", {y: "100%"}, {y: "0%", duration: 1, stagger: 0.25}, "-=1");
    tl.fromTo("#logo-blk", {y: "-400%", rotation: "-30"}, {y: "-100%", rotation: "0", 
        duration: 0.5}, "-=0.5");
}
```